# Как лучше оформить код с событием во vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Цель - показывать элемент ".modal" при нажатии на h1, и закрывать его при нажатии на document. Как это правильнее, элегантнее и лучше организовать? Я предложил пример, но мне потребовалось создать 2 функции show и show2, думаю это не очень рационально...

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      is: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.show2);
  },
  methods: {
    show() {
      this.is = !this.is;
    },
    show2(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'HTML') {
        this.is = false;
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <div class="modal" v-if="is"></div>
  <h1 @click.stop="show">Клик</h1>
  <div>
</template>
```